# Feed function line by line to iPython prompt using Java

Tags: java, python, function, process, runtime

I have a piece of Java code that executes iPython and then feeds it a number of commands, like so:

```
public static Process pr;
public static Reader bfr;
public static Writer bfw;     

...

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();      
pr = rt.exec("ipython");
bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
bfw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(pr.getOutputStream()));

String cmd = "print('test 1')";
cmd += "print('test 2')";

bfw.write(cmd);
bfw.flush();
```

This works fine for single-line commands (as above) and simple statements such as for loops, which can be written as one line. What I want to do, however, is feed also multi-line commands, such as functions, that I have saved in a file on my computer and that I load. I tried this (simplified example, my functions are actually much longer):

```
cmd += "def my_func(arg):\r\n"
cmd += "print(arg)\r\n"
```

but it gives me the following error, pointing to the end of the first line:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Is it possible to do what I want - to feed a complete function line by line to the iPython prompt?

Comment: What about passing cmd += "\tprint(arg)"?

Comment: And maybe one or two "\r\n" after.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. (In my question I forgot the \r\n after the second line, I've edited it.) The error points to the end of the first line, `def my_func(arg):`, by the way.

Comment: what is your os, windows?